# Notebook won't boot USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I purchased a Medion Notebook Education E11201 Intel Celeron N3450/4GB/64GB. When I try to boot a USB drive, it just shows a black screen with a non-blinking cursor. The funny thing is that I've tried the very same USB image on other devices and it booted without an issue.

The USB drive is a standard ISO file created with `dd`.

Things that I've tried:

- Format the USB drive with MBR.
- Format the USB drive with GPT.
- Format the USB drive with NTFS/FAT32.
- Disable the `Secure boot mode` in the setup.
- Try to boot directly changing the order in the setup.
- Try to boot using the boot menu (<kbd>F10</kbd>).

The notebook doesn't have a way to enable the Legacy BIOS mode, so it needs to be UEFI. However, the boot menu shows that the USB device is a UEFI device.

[image: Boot menu]

Any ideas why isn't the USB drive booting, or what needs to be changed to boot?

Comment: try making the usb using tools like rufus : https://rufus.ie/en/ {or are there any resons for not using any third party tool ?}

Comment: Tried Rufus as well, with the same result. I assume this is something related to the notebook, as I can boot the USB drive on a different PC/notebook.

Comment: Download UEFI Shell from the following link.  https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi  Rename it as bootx64.efi. Create a FAT/FAT32 formatted pen drive. (try both MBR as well as GPT one by one) Create \EFI\Boot folder therein. Place this bootx64.efi at \EFI\Boot on pen drive. Set boot mode UEFI and disable secure boot in firmware. Now try booting thru this pen drive and confirm if it can boot into UEFI Shell or not? Check if new Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) is available for your laptop and update the same and then check again. Continued...

Comment: What  ISO is on the USB drive? Is it some standard Windows / Linux distribution or something else? Is there \EFI\Boot folder with some bootloader .efi therein or not on the created USB drive? EFI Booting by default looks for .efi bootloader at \EFI\Boot folder on pen drive at a minimum.

Comment: In the Firmware setup, do you have any option like 'Boot from a file'? If so what if you point it to \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi on pen drive manually?

Comment: Referring to the link mentioned in the below answer from @harrymc it appears that you have a 32bit UEFI. As per UEFI Specs the firmware and OS should have same bitness to boot. i.e. a 32 bit UEFI can boot a 32 bit OS and 64 can boot a 64 bit OS. So also try booting using 32 bit version of EFI Shell downloaded from here https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/Ia32 You will have to rename this file now as bootia32.efi

Comment: Do you have the bios version and type?

Comment: @nKn CSM [Legacy] mode in UEFI should never be enabled, as its sole purpose was to support distros that did not yet support EFI boot circa <2017 - AFAIK, all distros support EFI boot and Windows has supported it since at least Win 7, so unless using a really old, non-updated AIO ISO _(such as Hiren's)_ or something like Easy2Boot, CSM [Legacy] boot should remain disabled and ignored. _(CSM Mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment and doing so will cause performance degradation - boot times increase by 400%+, GPT cannot be used in Windows, etc.)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article
[How to format Medion Akoya S2218 Laptop with Windows 10 using a USB and the EFI Shell](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/982/how-to-format-medion-akoya-s2218-laptop-with-windows-10-using-a-usb-and-the-efi-shell),
the procedure is as follows:

- Prepare the Windows 10 installation media,
  using the
  [Windows 10 Installation Media Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Boot with the option of "Internal Shell" (EFI Shell) from the
  Boot Menu
- From the displayed "Device mapping table", find the removable disk,
  named for example `blk1`
- Switch to the disk using the command `blk1:`
- Switch to the "/efi/boot" directory with the commands:

  ```
    cd efi
    cd boot
    dir
  ```
- Find the `.efi` file that corresponds to your hardware,
  probably `bootia32.efi`, type its name and press Enter
- The normal setup of windows will now start, so follow the
  prompts.

The above linked article has more details, with screenshots for every
step.

Comment: Yes, indeed, your post took me to the correct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `F2`, `F9` or `F11` to configure the BIOS/UEFI?

Something about to disabled secure boot...

Look:

- [Installing Linux on Medion Akoya S2218](https://community.medion.com/t5/Notebook-Netbook/Installing-Linux-on-Medion-Akoya-S2218/m-p/112881)
- [Redémarrage pc](https://community.medion.com/t5/Syst%C3%A8mes-d-exploitation/Red%C3%A9marrage-pc/td-p/77419) (in French).
- [How to restore the system of Windows devices | MEDION Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1r0rTxBZ7I).

Are you trying to install Linux or Windows?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.